# Tornado doesn't send Ajax response to client

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, tornado

Upon form submit the Tornado server does some checks and sends a response back to the client, which should appear in that current page as an `alert`.

Instead a blank html page is rendered with the `Json` response, but not as an `alert` on the current page where the form was submitted.

On submit the form is sent via `post` to `/dh (DataHandler)`

This is the Jquery:

```
$.post("/dh",function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    },"json");
```

The Tornado code:

```
class DataHandler(BaseHandler): 
    def post(self):

        # Checks are done with form data received

        dupInfo={
            'tel' : duptel,
            'name' : dupName
             }

        self.write(json.dumps(dupInfo, default=json_util.default))
        self.finish()
```

So how can you return this json to the current page?

Answer (score 3):

After the "alert" statement, add `return false;`. This disables the browser's default handling of the POST event. The browser's default behavior is to navigate to the new URL, and you want to prevent that.

Comment: Hi....I've added this after the `alert statement` but it still takes you to a blank html page.

Answer (score 0):

Give your form an id and stop the default redirect after submission:

```
$("#yourForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/dh",
        data: {
        // whatever data you are passing to handler
        },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST"
    }).done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       // call was successful
       // access response data
       alert(data['tel'])
       alert(data['name'])
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       // call error
       // access response data
       var data = jqXHR.responseJSON;
       alert(data['tel'])
       alert(data['name'])
    });
});
```

Based on your handler, you should end up in the done callback rather than the fail one.