# Tornado cannot read json ajax requests

Tags: jquery, python, tornado

Using `ajax` I'm trying to send data to my Tornado server, this is my JQuery:

```
$("#addTask").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var add = $('#addProject').val();
    var added={projectAdded:add};
      $.post("/task",
              JSON.stringify(added),
        function(data){
            window.location.reload(true);
              });
    });
```

The value of `$('#addProject').val();` is from an input text field:

```
$('<div class="input-group col-sm-7"><input type="text" form="task" class="form-control" id="addProject" name="projectAdd" value="" placeholder="New tag">
<button type="submit" name="addTag" value="addTag" form="task" id="addTask"></button>  </div>').appendTo('#proj');
```

In my Tornado server I have:

```
 class TaskAddHandler(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        addProj = json.loads(self.request.body)       
        print 'NEW TASK', addProj
```

But this gives me the error: `raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
                              ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`, instead of the value of the input text field.

Answer (score 4):

The data is in `self.request.arguments`. Also, you need to return valid json to the client.

```
class AjaxHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        my_data = self.request.arguments['test_data']
        # do something with my_data 
        self.write(json.dumps({'status': 'ok'}))
        self.finish()
```

The `self.write(json.dumps({'status': 'ok'}))` response from the handler is necessary to complete the transaction with the client: any valid json will do; it doesn't matter what the content is. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26739478/1599229) if the client does not seem to get the json back.)

It could also be that `_xsrf_cookies: True` in your `settings` within `run_server.py`. If that's the case, the `ajax` request itself will be blocked by Tornado (and you'll see `400 Bad Request` on the console).

To deal with that, "the `XSRF` token may... be passed via an `HTTP` header named `X-XSRFToken`," says the [doc](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/security.html). Set the cookie via the `get` of whatever page contains, or calls, that `ajax` logic, via `self.xsrf_token`. Doing so, the doc says, "is enough to set the cookie as a side effect":

```
class PageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.xsrf_token
        self.render('page.html')
```

Can then pick up the cookie in the client (here via the jQuery [$.cookie plugin](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js)):

```
var token = $.cookie('_xsrf');
```

Embed the token as a custom `headers` parameter in the call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/task',
    headers: {'X-XSRFToken' : token },
    data: {'test_string': 'test success'},
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: "POST",
    success: function ( data , status_text, jqXHR) {
        alert('ajax success')
    },
    error: function ( data , status_text, jqXHR ) {
        alert('ajax fail')
    },
});
```

Alternately, you can also put it as one of the fields in `data`. (And if you are `ajax`ing a JavaScript object as one of your fields, you **should** `JSON.stringify` it in order to get a nicely-structured `dict` back on the server side):

```
var packet = {"_xsrf": $.cookie("_xsrf"), "test_string": "test success", "js_obj": JSON.stringify(js_obj)}; 

$.ajax({
    url: '/task',
    data: packet,
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: "POST",
    success: function ( data , status_text, jqXHR) {
        alert('ajax success')
    },
    error: function ( data , status_text, jqXHR ) {
        alert('ajax fail')
    },
});
```

There is also an example of managing `_xsrf_cookies` in the [sample chat app](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/stable/demos/chat/static/chat.js) referred to in the [doc](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/structure.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to send a JSON string as your data, not the object.  Try JSON.stringify({projectAdded:add}) instead of just the object.

Comment: Thanks I've tried doing this, but it still gives the same error

Comment: Okay, looking at the jQuery doc it looks like JSON.stringify is not necessary anyway, presumably jQuery will automatically convert the object to JSON.  Are you possibly using Python 3?  When I switched my Tornado project from Python 2 to Python 3 I had to add .decode() to the self.request.body since Tornado was reading bytes and json.loads expected a string (which in Python 3 is unicode, not bytes).  However, I got a different error than you are seeing, so that may not be it.